# Java generic sorting class

Tags: java, sorting

I'm writing a class that will sort multiple types {arrays, arraylist, linkedlist} but I see there's a lot of code duplication. For instance, method to swap in list, and in arrays, method to sort list, and arrays etc. While I know code duplication is a bad practise, I am wondering if there's a better way to avoid writing duplicate code.

```
package utils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Sort {
    private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(List<E> sequence,
                                                       int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
        E temp = sequence.get(positionOne);
        sequence.set(positionOne, sequence.get(positionTwo));
        sequence.set(positionTwo, temp);
    }

    private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(E[] sequence,
                                                       int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
        E temp = sequence[positionOne];
        sequence[positionOne] = sequence[positionTwo];
        sequence[positionTwo] = temp;
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> selectionSort(List<E> sequence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
            int minPosition = -1;
            E minValue = sequence.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sequence.size(); j++) {
                E secondPosition = sequence.get(j);
                if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                    minPosition = j;
                    minValue = sequence.get(j);
                }
            }
            if (minPosition >= 0) {
                swap(sequence, i, minPosition);
            }
        }
        return sequence;
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] selectionSort(E[] sequence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
            int minPosition = -1;
            E minValue = sequence[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sequence.length; j++) {
                E secondPosition = sequence[j];
                if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                    minPosition = j;
                    minValue = sequence[j];
                }
            }
            if (minPosition >= 0) {
                swap(sequence, i, minPosition);
            }
        }
        return sequence;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] integers = {1, 6, 88, 7, 44, 3, 11};
        System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(integers));
        Sort.selectionSort(integers);
        System.out.println("Later: " + Arrays.toString(integers));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but why not use `Collections.sort()` and `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: @markspace so I could specify the sort I want to use like `Sort.insertionSort(myList)` and not use the default tim sort

Comment: You can treat arrays as lists with Arrays.asList(), as long as you don't want to insert or delete elements. I can't imagine much code similarity between an array-optimized sort and a linked-list-optimized sort, so I'd treat them differently anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing your code.

Your example is a typical case of *duplicated code* you have two places where the code looks very similar (and is logically the same) but has some minor differences.

On the other hand your example is a special case because we can simply convert the input of one of the duplicated parts to the form of the other one:

```
public class Sort {
    private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(List<E> sequence,
                                                       int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
        E temp = sequence.get(positionOne);
        sequence.set(positionOne, sequence.get(positionTwo));
        sequence.set(positionTwo, temp);
    }
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> selectionSort(List<E> sequence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
            int minPosition = -1;
            E minValue = sequence.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sequence.size(); j++) {
                E secondPosition = sequence.get(j);
                if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                    minPosition = j;
                    minValue = sequence.get(j);
                }
            }
            if (minPosition >= 0) {
                swap(sequence, i, minPosition);
            }
        }
        return sequence;
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] selectionSort(E[] sequence) {
        return selectionSort(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sequence))).toArray(new E[sequence.length]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] integers = {1, 6, 88, 7, 44, 3, 11};
        System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(integers));
        Sort.selectionSort(integers);
        System.out.println("Later: " + Arrays.toString(integers));
    }
}
```

However...

The more general approach is to *refactor* one (or both) of the *similar*  code fragments to make them (partially) *the same*.

In your example the difference at both places is the way the elements are addressed and accessed. We need to introduce an *indirection*, to provide an *input type independent* way to do this.

In this example an *interface* is the way to go:

```
interface MySequence<E extends Comparable<E>>{
  E getElementAt(int index);
  void setElementAt(int index, E element);
  int elementCount();
}
```

<sup>You could "reuse" method names from one of the duplicated parts but I intentionally use different names to make my point...</sup>

Now in each of the methods we first create an *anonymous inner class* from this interface. Lets start with the two `swap()` methods:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(List<E> sequence, int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence.get(index);
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence.set(index, element);
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.size();
        }
    };
    E temp = sequence.get(positionOne);
    sequence.set(positionOne, sequence.get(positionTwo));
    sequence.set(positionTwo, temp);
}
```

---

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(E[] sequence, int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence[index];
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence[index] = element;
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.length;
        }
    };
    E temp = sequence[positionOne];
    sequence[positionOne] = sequence[positionTwo];
    sequence[positionTwo] = temp;
}
```

Then we replace any following occurrence of `sequence` in that method with `mySequence`:

```
  private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(List<E> sequence, int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence.get(index);
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence.set(index, element);
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.size();
        }
    };
    E temp = mySequence.getElementAt(positionOne);
    mySequence.setElementAt(positionOne, mySequence.getElementAt(positionTwo));
    mySequence.setElementAt(positionTwo, temp);
}
```

You hopefully can do this for the other version of `swap()` yourself...

Now both `swap()` methods had a differing part (the *anonymous inner class* of type `MySequence`) and a *equal* part (the thee following lines).

<sup>Actually we have *more* code then before, but we are going to reduce it in a few minutes...</sup>

Select the three *identical* lines in one of the methods and
apply your IDEs *automated refactoring* `extract method` to create a new version of `swap()`:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(MySequence<E> mySequence, int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
    E temp = mySequence.getElementAt(positionOne);
    mySequence.setElementAt(positionOne, mySequence.getElementAt(positionTwo));
    mySequence.setElementAt(positionTwo, temp);
}

 private static  <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(List<E> sequence, int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence.get(index);
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence.set(index, element);
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.size();
        }
    };
    swap(mySequence, positionOne, positionTwo);
}
```

The replace the three  duplicated lines in the other original `swap()` method with a call to the new one too.

```
private  static <E extends Comparable<E>> void swap(E[] sequence, int positionOne, int positionTwo) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence[index];
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence[index] = element;
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.length;
        }
    };
    swap(mySequence, positionOne, positionTwo);
}
```

Next step is to remove the old versions of `swap()`. click on the name if one of these and invoke your IDEs *automated refactoring* `inline method`. Repeat this with the otehr old version too.

Now your `selectionSort()` methods look like this:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> selectionSort(List<E> sequence) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
        int minPosition = -1;
        E minValue = sequence.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sequence.size(); j++) {
            E secondPosition = sequence.get(j);
            if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                minPosition = j;
                minValue = sequence.get(j);
            }
        }
        if (minPosition >= 0) {
            MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
                public E getElementAt(int index) {
                    return sequence.get(index);
                }

                public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
                    sequence.set(index, element);
                }

                public int elementCount() {
                    return sequence.size();
                }
            };
            swap(mySequence, i, minPosition);
        }
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

Here we move the instantiation of `MySequence` to the top of each method:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> selectionSort(List<E> sequence) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence.get(index);
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence.set(index, element);
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.size();
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
        int minPosition = -1;
        E minValue = sequence.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sequence.size(); j++) {
            E secondPosition = sequence.get(j);
            if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                minPosition = j;
                minValue = sequence.get(j);
            }
        }
        if (minPosition >= 0) {
            swap(mySequence, i, minPosition);
        }
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

And again we change any further occurence of `sequence` within each method to `mySequence`:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> selectionSort(List<E> sequence) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence.get(index);
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence.set(index, element);
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.size();
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < mySequence.elementCount(); i++) {
        int minPosition = -1;
        E minValue = mySequence.getElementAt(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < mySequence.elementCount(); j++) {
            E secondPosition = mySequence.getElementAt(i);
            if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                minPosition = j;
                minValue = mySequence.getElementAt(i);
            }
        }
        if (minPosition >= 0) {
            swap(mySequence, i, minPosition);
        }
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

No we apply the same technique as with the `swap()` method. Move the *identical lines* of both methods to a new method using your IDEs  *automated refactoring* `extract method`:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void selectionSort(MySequence<E> mySequence) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mySequence.elementCount(); i++) {
        int minPosition = -1;
        E minValue = mySequence.getElementAt(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < mySequence.elementCount(); j++) {
            E secondPosition = mySequence.getElementAt(i);
            if (minValue.compareTo(secondPosition) > 0) {
                minPosition = j;
                minValue = mySequence.getElementAt(i);
            }
        }
        if (minPosition >= 0) {
            swap(mySequence, i, minPosition);
        }
    }
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> selectionSort(List<E> sequence) {
    MySequence<E> mySequence = new MySequence<E>() {
        public E getElementAt(int index) {
            return sequence.get(index);
        }

        public void setElementAt(int index, E element) {
            sequence.set(index, element);
        }

        public int elementCount() {
            return sequence.size();
        }
    };
    selectionSort(mySequence);
    return sequence; // ATTENTION! this line is NOT identical because of the type of sequence...
}
```

And replace the extracted part in the other original `selectionSort()` method too.

Thats it!

The code might even be shorter if we would use tree *functional interfaces* and *lambda expression* at the cost of more parameters at the new methods instead of one interface. But I doubt that it would increase readability and it definitely would add possibilities for errors.

The important insight is that we did not change the logic of the program since all changes we did are safe in that respect.

Nevertheless you should always have a set of automated *UnitTest* to guard your refactorings...

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborated answer! I will have to read it with a cup of coffee :)